# How UDP could be changed to support arbitrary block sizes?

Tags: udp, rtp

As we know the UDP places limit on the block size when the datagrampacket is sent from the client to the server. Still there are protocols like RTP which use UDP to transmit real time video/audio to the destination. I presume that the streaming of data will be variable in nature.

Could someone explain how does UDP manage to transmit variable block size over the internet? I have not found anything much in this regard.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How UDP could be changed to support arbitrary block sizes?

It does support arbitrary block sizes, up to 65507 bytes, more in IPv6.

> Could someone explain how does UDP manage to transmit variable block size over the internet?

It transmits variable block sizes within the limit, which is imposed not by UDP but by the path MTU at the IP layer and the socket send buffer at the application layer.

> I have not found anything much in this regard.

Hard to believe.